# Why a query that is searching through 1 million related records takes considerable time even after applying indexes?

Tags: c#, performance, entity-framework

```
var recordsStates = from s in db.Record
                    join ss in db.Record_State
                         on s.Id equals ss.RecordId
                    join apct in db.RecordTypesContentMapping
                         on new { t1 = ss.RecordId } equals new { t1 = apct.ContentId } into ss_apct
                    from apct in ss_apct.DefaultIfEmpty()
                    where (apct.ContentSourceName == null || apct.ContentSourceName == nameof(Record))
                           && ss.isCurrent && ss.StateId == (int)RecordStateType.Publish
                           && !ss.isDeleated && !s.isDeleted
                           && (searchRecords.CategoryIds.Count == 0 || searchRecords.CategoryIds.Contains((int)s.CategoryId))
                           && (string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchRecords.RecordTitle) || (string.IsNullOrEmpty(s.RecordNameModified) ?
                                                                                                s.RecordName.Contains(searchRecords.RecordTitle) :
                                                                                                s.RecordNameModified.Contains(searchRecords.RecordTitle)))
```

Each table has around 1 million records.

It takes around 7-8 seconds if I send the RecordTitle empty and takes 4-5 seconds if not empty.

I tried applying NC indexes on the subject title and whatnot. It’s of type `nvarchar(1000)`.

Every table is related via foreign key. I don’t know now what makes it slow.

Comment: Look at the generated SQL. Analyze the query plan

Comment: `nvarchar(1000)` type is not very good for indexing.

Comment: The last section looks strange. If `searchRecords.RecordTitle` is null or empty, you are doing either a `where s.RecordName.Contains(null)` or a `where s.RecordName.Contains('')` ! Are you sure this shouldn't be `!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchRecords.RecordTitle)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is probably Cartesian explosion

You either improve the query performance by linq to sql ( as you should ) or you can use Split query*.

- Note that : there is a possibility that split query can cause dirty data problems , think your first sql query done but before second sql query starts there could be data change with another request thus second query will continue with old data .

[Split query usage msdn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/single-split-queries)

[Cartesian explosion](https://justsimplycode.com/2021/11/07/cartesian-explosion-problem-in-entity-framework/)